# Problems to linebreak with an int in JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I'm having problems with a linebreak in a `JLabel`. I want to have a text(name) at the top and beneith the text I want to have an int(to keep score). I have tried this but the int does not show. It shows without the html code but on the same line.

```
JLabel p1 = new JLabel(<html>Player 1<br> " " </html> + pointPlayer1);
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
new JLabel("<html>Player 1<br>" + pointPlayer1 + "</html>");
```

The whole string must be inside the html opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
JLabel p1 = new JLabel("Player 1 \n "+ pointPlayer1);
```

Comment: Yes he can. It's even the easiest way to have a multi-line label. Your solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks but that is not working either. The html code works if I want to linebreak a text though.