# Including linebreak in StringBuilder

Tags: java, swing, newline, jlabel, stringbuilder

I'm having trouble trying to get a linebreak included in a Stringbuilder to appear in a JLabel.

I've found a couple of similar problems solved here, e.g. [here] [Problems to linebreak with an int in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325337/problems-to-linebreak-with-an-int-in-jlabel) and [here] [How do I append a newline character for all lines except the last one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448320/how-do-i-append-a-newline-character-for-all-lines-except-the-last-one) , along with a few others but none of them seem to work for me.

When printing to System.out, it works fine and I get a new line each time but when passed to a JLabel, everything appears as one line.

Here's the current version of the code, which has attempted to append a newline character, as well as including one in the main declaration. Neither has any effect when passed to the JLabel:

```
public void layoutCenter() {
    JPanel central = new JPanel();
    add(central, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    this.add(tabs);

    // memory tab
    StringBuilder mList = new StringBuilder();
    memLocList = new Memory[MEM_LOCATIONS]; //Memory is a separate class
    for (int i = 0; i < memLocList.length; i++) {
        mList.append("\n");
        memLocList[i] = null;
        mList.append("Memory location: " + i + " " + memLocList[i] + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println(mList.toString());

    JComponent memTab = makeTextPanel(mList.toString());
    tabs.addTab("Memory", memTab);

}

protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
    panel.add(filler);
    return panel;
}
```

I've also tried using System.getProperty(line.separator) with similar results and can't think of anything else to try so thought I'd appeal for help here.

Thanks,
Robert.

-EDIT-

Thanks to mKorbel, changing the JLabel to a JTextPane solved it.
The two lines in question are:

```
JTextPane filler = new JTextPane();
    filler.setText(text);
```

Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newline in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JLabel` isn't designated to held multilines document, there are two choices (by accepting newline or tab by default)

- if document could not be decorated or styled somehow then to use [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- in the case document could be decorated or styled somehow then to use [JEditorPane or JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: Thank you mKorbel,

I changed it to JTextpane and it now formats correctly.

Much appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, although this works very well, it takes a while to start up. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
(without the obvious, "don't use Java.")

Comment: the same start_up became from all programing languages, plus minus citibus,

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to use <html> and <br> to get line breaks in a JLabel Swing component.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert,

I already tried using this:

    mList.append("<html>Memory location: " + i + " " + memLocList[i]
     + "<br></html>");

but no luck with that either.

Comment: @Robert: Maybe I'm not understanding what you wrote, but you have no text after the break.

Comment: @ Gilbert: Sorry, my additional comment isn't very clear. It's part of a loop and I wanted a line-break after each iteration.

Comment: @Robert: Ok.  A JTextPane is more appropriate for what you want, as you commented.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must use `JLabel`, then I suggest using one for each line.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a JLabel have mulitple lines by wrapping the text in HTML tags and using br tags to add a new line.

If you news auto wrapping I suggest using a JTexrArea. You can make it uneditable and style it so it looks like a label.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

One of the example is using html to make it two lines for a JButton text. It should be very similar.